# Is it possible to check if a short sequence of text is random or not?

Tags: algorithm, entropy, text-analysis

Is it possible to check if a short sequence of text, e.g. two or three words, is random or not?
My first thought was to calculate the entropy on the string.

```
H("hello world") = 2.84535
H("sdzfjksher") = 3.12193
```

but any combination of the chars in `"hello world"` will result in the same entropy, but will create a random string like `"llloo ehrdw"`. Entropy based methods works great on long strings like text. Here you can also count single chars to determinate that its a language. You can also use Zipfs Law here to check for real languages...

the next method would be a lookup table of common words, like a normal english dictionary. The problem with this method is to create a list of words first.

For example:

```
input string        result
------------------------------------------------------
"hello world"       matches 2 words
"helloworld"        random string
"lllooehrdw"        random string
"hello.world"       probably 2 words 
"a.be.was"          probably 3 words (but this is probably a strange edge case)
```

So its all about finding words here to compare them with your wordlist, which can be really hard.

Another problem with all these methods could be, that they only detect certain languages or need to be trained to a certain language. Consider that we only want to use english for now.

So is there any good method to do this, or do i need to accept False Positives and False Negatives?

Comment: I'm afraid this is AI-complete.

Comment: (Or if not, it will at least require a whole database with all the common English words.)

Comment: yes of course, also see the last string which could be random but also consists of three words...

Comment: but there must be any characteristic in language that is not in random? Like the usage of uncommon characters. so if i have a word "zzyycxyx" this is probably random because it contains a lot of z,x,y and has no vocals in it..

Comment: What is the original problem you are trying to solve? Perhaps there is a workaround or a way to solve the original problem in an easier way? For example, trying to detect people entering nonsense data in forms.

Comment: @Sysyphus: the original problem is just that: check if a short sequence of text is random or not

Comment: What you are looking for is a character-level n-gram language model. Random sequences of text will have higher *perplexity* than non-random sequences. A full discussion of language models is beyond the scope of SO format, unfortunately.

Comment: @reox were you able to find an approach to this problem?

Comment: @iam.Carrot no, it might be even close to impossible to get this working for short strings. For long strings it is much easier.

Comment: @reox oh that's bad considering I have strings at max of length 5

Comment: @iam.Carrot considering you have a maximum string length, a dictionary approach might be useful. This approach only works if you know the input language though.

Answer (score 0):

You could count the frequency of characters used in the text and compare this with known character distributions in English and/or other languages. This will give an indication of the probability that the text is/resembles that language or not.

Comment: Even better, use the frequency of letter pairs. If you use 26 letters, you only have 26x25/2 pairs to consider. You can generate the letter pair frequencies easily from a large slab of text (or a dictionary). I would have 27 characters - a..z plus a generic word delimiter; this also checks the frequencies of the first and last characters in a word.

Comment: For very short texts, the number of pairs might be too low for significance. Also I don't see why you would only count combinations instead of all possible pairs of two letters (26^2).

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to use the frequencies of the letters to see if a string is a word or random letter.
http://scottbryce.com/cryptograms/stats.htm

Combining statistics and wordlists sounds like the way to go reduce false positives.

Comment: The URL gives a 404.

Comment: these days sounds like perfect task for some ML model